# ActionBlock.Complete.Wait(token) does not wait for the pipeline to complete

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have a TPL Dataflow Pipeline in with Conditional link flow of a message could end at either of the action blocks as shown in the picture.
[image]

I also have  PropogateCompletion set to True, this is the same link options used throughout the pipeline.

Once I start the Process by passing in a context to the first TransformBlock it kicks off the process context holds start and end time and some metrics of how many records its processing.

Pipeline method.

```cs
public void  Process(CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true};
            var exBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {CancellationToken = token, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount};
            _context.Start();

            var setMessagesToStartStatus = new TransformBlock<IContext, IContext>(async context =>
            {
                await _mRepository.SetMessagesToStartStatus(token);
                return context;
            }, exBlockOptions);
            var autoMapMessageReferences =
                new TransformBlock<IContext, IContext>(async context =>
                    {
                        await _mRepository.SetAutoMapMessageReferences(token);
                        return context;
                    },
                    exBlockOptions);
            var messagesToProcess = new TransformManyBlock<IContext, AwsomeMessage>(
                async context =>
                {
                    var r = await _mRepository.GetPendingMessagesToProcess(token);
                    return r.ToList();
                }, exBlockOptions);
            var errActionBlock =
                new ActionBlock<AwsomeMessage>(async inMessage =>
                {
                    await _mRepository.SetToErrorState(inMessage.MessageId, inMessage.ErrorMessage, token);
                    _errorWorks.Add(inMessage);
                }, exBlockOptions);

            var printActionBlock = new ActionBlock<AwsomeMessage>(inMessage =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"ID :{inMessage.MessageId}, Error?: {inMessage.IsInError}, ErrorString :: {inMessage.ErrorMessage}");
                _processedWorks.Add(inMessage);
            }, exBlockOptions);
            var updateSourceSystem = EnrichSourceSystemTransBlock(token, exBlockOptions);
            var detoxReasonUpdate = EnrichDetoxReasonTransBlock(exBlockOptions);
            var awsomeActionMapping = EnrichAwsomeActionMappingTransBlock(token, exBlockOptions);
            var lateReasonMapToWorkAction = EnrichLateReasonTransBlock(exBlockOptions);
            var updateWithNarrationReason = EnrichReasonToOtherTransBlock(token, exBlockOptions);
            var crossAmendedByAndOtherReason = EnrichCrossSystemTransBlock(exBlockOptions);
            var PureEQDBookReplacement = EnrichPurexBookTransBlock(token, exBlockOptions);
            var bookHierarchyEnrichMessage = EnrichBookHierarchyTransBlock(token, exBlockOptions);

            //pipeline
            setMessagesToStartStatus.LinkTo(autoMapMessageReferences, linkOptions);
            autoMapMessageReferences.LinkTo(messagesToProcess, linkOptions);
            messagesToProcess.LinkTo(updateSourceSystem, linkOptions);
            updateSourceSystem.LinkTo(detoxReasonUpdate, linkOptions);
            detoxReasonUpdate.LinkTo(awsomeActionMapping, linkOptions);
            awsomeActionMapping.LinkTo(errActionBlock, linkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
            awsomeActionMapping.LinkTo(lateReasonMapToWorkAction, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
            lateReasonMapToWorkAction.LinkTo(updateWithNarrationReason, linkOptions);
            updateWithNarrationReason.LinkTo(errActionBlock, linkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
            updateWithNarrationReason.LinkTo(crossAmendedByAndOtherReason, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
            crossAmendedByAndOtherReason.LinkTo(PureEQDBookReplacement, linkOptions);
            PureEQDBookReplacement.LinkTo(errActionBlock, linkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
            PureEQDBookReplacement.LinkTo(bookHierarchyEnrichMessage, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
            bookHierarchyEnrichMessage.LinkTo(errActionBlock, linkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
            bookHierarchyEnrichMessage.LinkTo(printActionBlock, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);


            //Create Context 
            setMessagesToStartStatus.Post(_context);

            //Kick off complete. -- Mark the head to say its complete.
            try
            {
                setMessagesToStartStatus.Complete();
                printActionBlock.Completion.Wait(token);
                errActionBlock.Completion.Wait(token);
                _context.Complete();
            }
            catch (AggregateException exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                foreach (var exc in exception.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Err Msg = {exc.Message}, Stack Work = {exc.StackTrace} ");
                }

                throw exception.InnerExceptions.Single();
            }
        }
```

I tried Task.WhenAll some how it just gets no where. it just blocks.
as propagate complete is true i tried setMessagesToStartStatus.Complete.Wait()

when i do that as soon as complete is true it just does not wait here it says task ran to completion and moves on.

GetMessages from db is a TransformManyBlock, When i pass a test data of only one item which goes to the error block it now gets into a hung state as print block is not even started. so complete wont take affect. and the other issue is its not waiting.

FIXED with the following code.

```
 var completeFalseLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropagateCompletion = false};

    //Linking changes.
    .LinkTo(errActionBlock, completeFalseLinkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
        awsomeActionMapping.LinkTo(lateReasonMapToWorkAction, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
        lateReasonMapToWorkAction.LinkTo(updateWithNarrationReason, linkOptions);
        updateWithNarrationReason.LinkTo(errActionBlock, completeFalseLinkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
        updateWithNarrationReason.LinkTo(crossAmendedByAndOtherReason, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
        crossAmendedByAndOtherReason.LinkTo(PureEQDBookReplacement, linkOptions);
        PureEQDBookReplacement.LinkTo(errActionBlock, completeFalseLinkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
        PureEQDBookReplacement.LinkTo(bookHierarchyEnrichMessage, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);
        bookHierarchyEnrichMessage.LinkTo(errActionBlock, completeFalseLinkOptions, x => x.IsInError);
        bookHierarchyEnrichMessage.LinkTo(printActionBlock, linkOptions, x => !x.IsInError);

//and Complete Wait here.

setMessagesToStartStatus.Complete();
printActionBlock.Completion.Wait(token);
//manually complete the error block.
errActionBlock.Complete();
errActionBlock.Completion.Wait(token);
_context.Complete();
```

Comment: Completion *won't* be propagated if a block has messages in its input or output queue. If no link condition matches a message, that message will remain in the output buffer. Check the blocks, their status and their buffers in the debugger to see which one hasn't completed

Comment: Also make sure your on the latest correct version of the [Dataflow Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/). Older/alternate versions would only propagate completion to one linked block, latest versions will propagate to all linked blocks.

Comment: I am using .NetCore 2.2 and Nuget package @Latest

Comment: The other obvious thing to check is whether your in a single threaded context. It's typically best to `await` the completion tasks in an async method instead of blocking with `wait`.

Comment: I repro'd your pipeline in a console app and it completes properly, except that `bookHierarchyEnrichMessage.LinkTo(errActionBlock, linkOptions, linkOptions, x => x.IsInError);` doesn't compile obviously. So it's unlikely that there's anything wrong with your pipeline setup and more likely that one of your blocks is just getting backed up.

Comment: I am testing with only one message from the repository with NSubstitute which will error. then it starts to block at printAction saying the WaitingForActivation and would not go forward at all. corrected the linkOptions issue. it was me copy pasting.

Comment: after some poking around looks like errBlock is completed already and hence it gets stuck at the hierarchy block. and bookHierarchyEnrichMessage is not able to post to the error block and its dead.